# Input UTF8 data conveniently to MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I'm from Hungary which makes things complicated if talking about character encoding. When I code websites I cannot avoid storing simple data in MySQL which normally would not require an admin surface to handle. I mean I would not make an admin for recording menu names in a table. But I have to. Since it's impossible (or I haven't found a solution yet) to record UTF8 attributes in phpMyadmin. **My input stays ISO-8859-2 encoded in the UTF8 field as I send it via phpMyadmin.** If I send data to the database using an UTF8 webpage, UTF8 form, everything UTF, I have absolutely no problem.

So my point is that it's circumstantial and time-consuming to make an admin surface or something like that every time I want to insert some UTF8 to an UTF8 encoded database. phpmyadmin is unusable for me. But I don't feel like programming another phpmyadmin on my own. It would make no sense. There must be a solution. Can you help?

[image: Actual UTF8 attributes show off the right way. The line marked with blue line has been recorded with phpmyadmin and is not stored as UTF8.]

(Actual UTF8 attributes show off the right way. The line marked with blue line has been recorded with phpmyadmin and is not stored as UTF8.)

Comment: phpMyAdmin works perfectly fine with UTF-8. You may simply have misconfigured it. How do you figure that your "input stays ISO-8859 encoded"? This makes little sense.

Comment: It's a returning problem for me on every database I've ever used. Let it be in USA, Europe, absolutely unrelated servers and configurations. I get the same problem everywhere. If I input something via phpmyadmin, it's LATIN-2 only. Even if the field is UTF8.

Comment: How do you figure the input is "Latin2"? What leads you to this conclusion? Details, man, details! :)

Comment: Look at the picture I've just added.

Comment: In the screenshot you show we see that **characters** are stored nicely as they should be (blue arrow). It doesn't say anything about what **encoding** they're in. If you think that the garbage above is "actual UTF-8" then you need to read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and my guess below is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just take a very wild stab into the dark:

phpMyAdmin actually gets it right. The one that isn't working is your custom interface, because it's not setting the *connection encoding* correctly. So all the data you insert via it is messed up in the database but happens to have a clean roundtrip in your application. phpMyAdmin inserts *actual* UTF-8 data, which messes up when retrieved via your wrong connection.

See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: I know how to use UTF8 with php, please link a resource about the setup in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Well, just to 100% rule out any possibility about *your* PHP script being wrong: what have you set the SQL connection encoding to and how?

Comment: When I record data via PHP, I use UTF-8 headers, a form with UTF8 encoding, and the .php file itself is UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: **But you're not setting the SQL connection encoding!** Go read the abovelinked articles.

Answer (score 2):

For those who might find this article in the future with the same problem, I've set the connection encoding right after setting up the connection using this query:

`SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you. After a while, I figure out the solution, using a utf8-to-html online converter at
[Convert to HTML](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php)
. Just type your Unicode text and copy the result, paste into your PHPMyadmin.